# Finding $n^{th}$ term of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

$$3,8,17,32,57,\ldots$$
How do we find the $n^{th}$ term? I have been roaming aimlessly for a few minutes now. A definite pattern is in the differences of differences. Hints will be apreciated.

Comment: http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071208001733AAJEOtJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$3,8,17,32,57,\cdots$$

Taking the differences of consecutive terms  $$5,9,15,25,\cdots$$

Taking the differences of consecutive terms $$4,6,10,\cdots$$

Taking the differences of consecutive terms $$2,4,\cdots,\text{ whose } n\text{ term } =2^n$$

The $n$ th term of $4,6,10,\cdots$ will be  $2^n+(n$ th term of $2,2,2,\cdots)$ i.e., $2^n+2$

The $n$ th term of  $5,9,15,25\cdots$ will be   $2^n+2+(n$th term of $1,3,5,\cdots)$ i.e., $2^n+2+(2n-1)$

The $n$ th term of  $3,8,17,32,57,\cdots$ will be $(2^n+2+2n-1)+(n$ th term of $-2,-1,2,7\cdots)$

Now the $n$ th term of $-2,-1,2,7\cdots$ can be found to be $(n-1)^2-2$ by similar difference method.

Answer (score 3):

[From OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=3,8,17,32,57&language=english&go=Search), the sequence is 
$$2^n + n^2$$

Comment: I was hovering along the same direction almost.Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let p(n) be the nth prime. Let o(n) be the nth term in OEIS sequence A190525, the number of n-step one-sided prudent walks. The given sequence is clearly:

p(1) + o(1), p(3) + o(2), p(5)+ o(3), p(7)+ o(4), p(9)+o(5),..., p(2n-1)+o(n).

Answer (score 0):

This can be anything you want, you only have to choose a particular pattern.

Comment: I had forseen this answer even before I ever posted this question.